# PHP array product combinations

Tags: php, arrays, multiplication

I have produced an array of prime factors of a number - this is supposed to be the hard part! However, in order to create a list of the divisors of the same number the prime factors need to be combined in every which possible way.  Something that I'm struggling to do with php.

For example I have an array of:

```
2
2
2
3
3
41
53
```

...for the number 156456; multiply them all together and you get back to the number.  What I need to do is to multiply all of the duos together e.g. 2x2, 2x3, 2x53 etc and then all of the triplets together and so on until I finally multiply the 7 blocks of six together.

As you can see this will give a very large array with all of the divisors in, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12 etc.  with many duplicates.  I just can't seem to get from the array I have above to this array of divisors that I want.  It's a case of multiplying out every possible combination of elements in the array, is there a php function for this, my search so far has been fruitless?

Comment: use [array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique) to remove duplicates

Comment: There is no such official PHP function. You will have to write your own algorithm. Or you can try finding an open source implementation.

Comment: Can anyone give me a point in the right direction, my guess is that I find out how many elements are in the array and then loop through so for the above I would have 6 loops where I brought duos in and then triplets in etc, but still not sure how to implement

Comment: I can't see what you want. What do you mean duos, triplets, 7 blocks of six? Maybe you could clarify that paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading this page: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.02.06/joe1.html, I tried to build something that might work, It may not be the most efficient solution and its also limited to `count($primes) <= 32` on 32 bit systems. If you need more, feel free to use a [Bitset](http://pecl.php.net/package/Bitset):

```
$primes = Array(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 41, 53);
$num_primes = count($primes); // 7, if this is over 32, it won't work on 32bit systems
$divisors = Array();

// number of possible combinations
$limit = pow(2, $num_primes) - 1; // 127

// count a number up and use the binary 
// representation to say which index is
// part of the current divisor
for($number = 0; $number <= $limit; $number++) {
    $divisor = 1;
    // only multiply activated bits in $number to the divisor
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_primes; $i++) {
        $divisor *= ($number >> $i) & 1 ? $primes[$i] : 1;
    }
    $divisors[] = $divisor;
}

echo implode(", ", array_unique($divisors));
```

This results into the following divisors:

```
1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 12, 24, 9, 18, 36, 72, 41, 82, 164, 328, 123, 246, 492,
984, 369, 738, 1476, 2952, 53, 106, 212, 424, 159, 318, 636, 1272, 477,
954, 1908, 3816, 2173, 4346, 8692, 17384, 6519, 13038, 26076, 52152, 19557,
39114, 78228, 156456
```

To find all divisors you need to multiply each prime factor with each other in every possible combination. To do this I calculate the number of possible combinations (`$limit`). If you now count a number up to this limit the binary representation looks something like this:

```
7 bit
<----->
0000000    0
0000001    1
0000010    2
0000011    3
0000100    4
0000101    5
0000110    6
0000111    7
0001000    8
0001001    9
...
1111110  126
1111111  127
```

The current binary representation of `$number` represents which indexes of `$primes` are used to calculate the current `$divisor`. To show this better let's say `$number = 5`, which is `0000101` in binary. And the calculation for `$divisor` would be `2 * 1 * 2 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 = 4`. Only the first and the third bit is set, so only the first and the third element in the array is used for the calculation.

I hope this makes it a little bit clearer.

Comment: What can I say, perfection.  I'll have a look to see what the first number is with more than 32 prime factorials but otherwise it has answered the question very well.  Thank you.

Comment: ...actually it must be 2^33 which is 8,589,934,592 which is as high as I need to go, problem solved.